# How to save variable into a file (like print but into file)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am asking how to save a text file in python, that can contain a variable.
I didn't tried anything because I am a beginner.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Comment: You can redirect the built-in [`print()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) function's output to an open file by specifying the keyword `file=`.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say you have a file called file and it is a notepad (text/txt) document. Your code would go like this:

```
text = "This can be anything"
with open("file.txt", "w") as myfile:
    myfile.write(text)
```

[The tutorial on reading and writing files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) should help if you don't understand this. The w means that you can write to the file.